# In Perl subversion bindings how do I dtermine if a directory is in a working copy

Tags: perl, svn

I'm using the perl Subversion bindings (SVN::Client et al). If I have a directory path, how do I determine if that path is part of a working copy - it must be fast.

Before svn 1.7 one could check for a path/.svn directory, but obviously that doesn't work in svn 1.7 with a single higher level .svn directory.  I can't just recurse directories upwards for .svn, as that will fail in non-tracked directories far under a working copy.

```
$SVN::Error::handler = undef;
$client->status2($path, undef, sub {
    my ($path,$wc_status2) = @_;
    if ($wc_status2->entry()) { it exists }
```

seems close, but this returns an error (I suppress) if the path is outside a working copy, and benchmarks fairly slow.  I suspect there's some basic function I'm missing in my reading.  Thanks much.

Comment: Simply checking for a `.svn` directory is not a great test anyway, since something else besides SVN could easily do a `mkdir .svn`. I would use `status` instead of `status2`, since there's no point in checking externals. Make sure to set `$recursive`, `$get_all`, and `$update` to `0` and to `return` from the `status_func` subroutine immediately after checking the first path. You might also try the `url_from_path` method, but I have no idea if it would be faster or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with SVN::Client, but `svn info` gives `Working Copy Root Path`. Perhaps it is possible to access this with SVN::Client::info. In fact, if you are only interested in whether a directory is under Subversion control, `svn info` output may be sufficient.